# Как картографическое приложение хранит данные об объектах?

Tags: карты, картография

Ко мне пришла идея для пет проекта(исключительно в обучающих целях), создать свое очень небольшое картографическое приложение. Меня интересует вопрос, как картографические приложения хранят данные о геолокации объектов? К примеру, что из себя представляет дорога? Просто цепочку координат ? Как хранятся границы объектов, например большого здания и нужно ли их хранить, или адрес объекта - это просто одна пара координат без границ?  Буду благодарен любой информации и ссылкам на источники.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KML